# Unable to update Javascript Object property in Object's function call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a CONTACT javascript object. I call CONTACT.load() to read the data for CONTACT.id through $.ajax(). On success, I am able to use the data returned by the ajax() call. Then I save some of the read data in object properties. However, the saved property values are lost. Here is my code:

```
var CONTACT=
{
id: 1,
referrals_loaded: false,
city: '',
};



CONTACT.load = function(cb)
{
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contactAjax.php",
        data: { 
            ContactID: this.id,
            actionID: 'LOAD_CONTACT_DATA',
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            success = true;
            var address = data['address'];
            var addr = address[0];

            this.city =  addr['city'].trim();
            console.log("City (in ajax() ):" +this.city);
            var province = addr['province'].trim();
            // ... 


            if (typeof cb==='function') (cb)();
        },
        error: function () {

            alert("Could not load Contact data through LOAD_CONTACT_DATA .");
        }
    });

console.log("City (after ajax() ):" +this.city);

}
```

My calling code is like this:

```
CONTACT.id = 123456;
CONTACT.load('testtest');

function testtest()    {
   console.log("Contact city is " + CONTACT.city);  
   CONTACT.city = "London";
   console.log("Contact city is " + CONTACT.city);  
}
```

And the console.log O/P is like this:

```
City (in ajax() ):MARKHAM  
Contact city in testtest()  
Contact city is London
```

Notice that when I set the value for CONTACT.city again in testtest(), the object retains the property value. Could someone please explain, why the CONTACT.city becomes empty when testest() is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'this' refers to a different object.

```
CONTACT.load = function(cb)
{
var self = this; // common hack
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contactAjax.php",
        data: { 
            ContactID: this.id,
            actionID: 'LOAD_CONTACT_DATA',
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            success = true;
            var address = data['address'];
            var addr = address[0];

            self.city =  addr['city'].trim();  // <-- assign to correct object
            console.log("City (in ajax() ):" +this.city);
            var province = addr['province'].trim();
            // ... 


            if (typeof cb==='function') (cb)();
        },
        error: function () {

            alert("Could not load Contact data through LOAD_CONTACT_DATA .");
        }
    });

console.log("City (after ajax() ):" +this.city);

}
```